# Download Multiple Profile Photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is what i am doing right now.

```
 foreach($response['data'] as $friends_phtoos) {
     $f_id = $friends_phtoos['id'];
     $img = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$f_id.'/picture';
     $image = $f_id.'.jpg';
getFacebookPhoto($img, $image);
 }
```

I am doing this loop for maximum 10 photos
However it is taking lot of time to download all the 10 photos.

What is the best way to get those photos quickly?
I have heard about **batch**. But I don't know how to use it with PHP.

getFacebookPhoto function is a curl function to download photos.
Can I use curl to get Facebook photos? Is it against FB's terms and condition? (additional question ;)

Comment: I got negative vote for this question :) We are here to optimize others work. I shared my work and asked help. Still negative vote :) Surprised!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making 10 API calls which is slowing you down. There is no problem with using curl, but since I don't know what your `getFacebookPhoto` function looks like I'm going to use `file_get_contents` to give you a complete solution.

The trick is to make one API call and get all the photos. Using the Graph API path `/ID/photo/` also slows things down a little as this results in a 301 redirect to the user's photo. I'm going to use FQL since it's a lot quicker. This gives you an array with IDs and URLs to the Facebook photo. Don't assume that the data will come back in the same order you send the IDs.

```
$f_id = array();
foreach($response['data'] as $friends_phtoos) {
     $f_id[] = $friends_phtoos['id'];
 }
$ids = implode(',',$f_id);
$fql = "SELECT id, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN ({$ids})";
$url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=' . urlencode($fql);
$fb_photos = json_decode( file_get_contents($url) );
```

Comment: **getFacebookPhoto** saves the pics in server. Is that against fb's terms and conditions? I use culr to download them.

Comment: It depends on how you're using them. You can legally cache them for a "short period", but you should update them when the owner changes their photo. I find it's easier just to pull them fresh at each page load as determined by an external cache.

Answer (score -1):

Considering there is nothing special about this forloop, the problem most likely lies with your download. The reason this is taking so long has nothing to do with your implementation but most likely with the download speed itself.

Comment: I have good download speed on my dedicated server. It has 1gbps port. What could be the average download speed for this download?

Comment: @MaheshKumar It might not necessarily be on your end. It might be on facebook's end.

Comment: It is sad to hear this. There is no way to speed it up?

Comment: **getFacebookPhoto** this function downloads ten photos one by one. Is there a way to do it at once? So I can save lot of timing.